# XCode 5 Hangs during App Submit

Tags: xcode, xcode5

When I try to submit Apps to store using XCode 5, Validation will crash the XCode, Distribute will work but after around 20 minutes of working. I had this problem with XCode 5 GM and the new XCode 5 that is stable (released on September, 18th).

I did all kind of recreating the provisions, refreshing the identities in Preferences -> Account etc. Tried 4 different apps, No difference.

Is there any solution for this? Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: I dont usnderstand 100% how does it crash? is there any message error let me know

Comment: give us the crash report. it is no general issue and likely a prob with your environment

Comment: There is no crash report. It just wait and wait until you force it close or terminate the process. I waited like 4 hours!

Comment: then sample the OSX app to see where it waiting maybe.

Answer (score 2):

This has been the issue for lots of people when you try to validate and distribute your app to appstore.

To fix this issue,you will have to create a New Provisioning Profile for distribution.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Farhad:If your problem is solved then please upvote for it and accept the answer.